# Does MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (All file access) permission exist?

Tags: android, permissions, storage

Are there any permissions in Android like MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or it just simply a category term for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? Is it introduced in Android 11? Please help me on this doubt.

Comment: `Does MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (All file access) permission exist?` Yes. It exists.

Comment: Thanks blackapps.. tested in Android 11.. I am able to use permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE..